# Can Scala reflect static method?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, static

I have a java library, and I'd like to call some static functions from the library by Scala using reflection. I tried to use the java way that I created `URLClassloader` and reflected the method by `getDeclaredMethod()`, but it seems not working in Scala. And I was thinking about the Scala way, but it seems no method or field can be reflected without a specific instance is created.
So is it possible to reflect static method in Scala? And if it is, what's the proper way to do?

Sorry, I think I made a mistake, it works fine with the java api. Thanks guy..

Comment: *"it seems not working in Scala"* Not working how exactly?

Comment: Can you add your 'not working' code? And explain better what 'not working' actually means?

Comment: It works just the same as in Java. You can use all of the Java reflection API, and it works identically in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this, after finding this question in my search, so to save people who also find this question by Googling:

If you have a scala `TypeTag` or `WeakTypeTag`, it is in fact possible to get the `java.lang.Class` object for the underlying java class, and from there you can use the java reflection API to do what you want to do:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val wt = weakTypeTag[java.text.DateFormat]
wt: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[java.text.DateFormat] = TypeTag[java.text.DateFormat]

scala> val clazz = wt.mirror.runtimeClass(wt.tpe)
clazz: Class[_] = class java.text.DateFormat

scala> val fld = clazz.getDeclaredField("SHORT")
fld: java.lang.reflect.Field = public static final int java.text.DateFormat.SHORT

scala> val meth = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getTimeInstance", fld.getType)
meth: java.lang.reflect.Method = public static final java.text.DateFormat java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance(int)

scala> val methResult = meth.invoke(null, fld.get(null))
methResult: Object = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@b4dc7db3

scala> methResult.asInstanceOf[java.text.Format].format(System.currentTimeMillis)
res28: String = 9:15 AM
```

Hat tip to [the accepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901823/any-way-to-obtain-a-java-class-from-a-scala-2-10-type-tag-or-symbol) which pointed me in the right direction.

Note that scala methods on companion objects are a whole different kettle of fish. [This different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399998/is-it-possible-to-generate-apply-from-weaktypetag-inside-a-scala-macro) might help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you referring to the functionality of Scala's native runtime reflection API provided in scala-reflect.jar, then the answer is two-fold:

1. It is possible to invoke "static" methods written in Scala (i.e. methods defined in objects).
2. It is not possible to invoke static methods written in Java (here's an issue for that: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6459).