# Scala - implicit macros & materialisation

Tags: scala, macros, implicit-conversion, implicit

*The* use cases for implicit macros is supposed to be the so-called "materialisation" of type class instances.

Unfortunately, the example in the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html) is a bit vague on how that is achieved.

> Upon being invoked, the materializer can acquire a representation of T and generate the appropriate instance of the Showable type class.

Let's say I have the following trait ...

```
trait PrettyPrinter[T]{
  def printed(x:T) : String
}
object PrettyPrinter{
  def pretty[T](x:T)(implicit pretty:PrettyPrinter[T]) = pretty printed x

  implicit def prettyList[T](implicit pretty :PrettyPrinter[T]) = new PrettyPrinter[List[T]] {
    def printed(x:List[T]) = x.map(pretty.printed).mkString("List(",", ",")")
  }
}
```

and three test classes

```
class A(val x:Int)
class B(val x:Int)
class C(val x:Int)
```

Now I understand that instead of writing the following boilerplate

```
implicit def aPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[A] {def printed(a:A) = s"A(${a.x})"}
implicit def bPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[B] {def printed(b:B) = s"B(${b.x})"}
implicit def cPrinter = new PrettyPrinter[C] {def printed(c:C) = s"C(${c.x})"}
```

we should be able to add

```
implicit def materialise[T] : PrettyPrinter[T] = macro implMaterialise[T]
def implMaterialise[T](c:blackbox.Context):c.Expr[PrettyPrinter[T]] = {
  import c.universe._

  ???
}
```

to the `object PrettyPrinter{...}` which then generates the corresponding `PrettyPrinters` on demand ... how? How do I actually get that "representation of T"?

If I try `c.typeOf[T]`, for example, "No TypeTag available for T".

**UPDATE**

Trying to use class tags doesn't seem to work either.

```
implicit def materialise[T:ClassTag] : PrettyPrinter[T] = macro implMaterialise[T]
def implMaterialise[T:ClassTag](c:blackbox.Context):c.Expr[PrettyPrinter[T]] = {
  import c.universe._

  ???
}
```

results in

```
Error:(17, 69) macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences
implicit def materialise[T:ClassTag] : PrettyPrinter[T] = macro implMaterialise[T]
                                                                ^
```

*update2*

Interestingly, using `WeakTypeTags` doesn't really change anything as

```
implicit def materialise[T:WeakTypeTag]: PrettyPrinter[T] = macro implMaterialise[T]
def implMaterialise[T](c:blackbox.Context)(implicit evidence : WeakTypeTag[T]):c.Expr[PrettyPrinter[T]]
= {
  import c.universe._

  ???
}
```

will result in

```
Error:(18, 71) macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences
implicit def materialise[T:WeakTypeTag]: PrettyPrinter[T] = macro implMaterialise[T]
                                           ^
```

Comment: No need for macros here. It should just work with `PrettyPrinter.pretty(List(A(2)))`

Comment: @Reactormonk Thanks for your comment. However, no it won't because ``pretty`` will not find an instance of ``PrettyPrinter[A]``. If you would please read the question before commenting, you will notice that the point of using a macro is wanting to avoid having to write boilerplate code defining a ``PrettyPrinter`` for each class. You will also notice that I am not interested in alternative non-macro solutions - if such exist - because I'm asking this question to better understand the use case from the macro documentation.

Comment: `T: TypeTag` - shapeless uses macros, you could take a look at these for generic derivations.

Comment: Found one: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/ab081796c183530efdd8b29dab8fee1fee7c61f9/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/nat.scala#L77

Comment: @Reactormonk I don't see how this helps. They simply match an AST node and check if it's one they expected ... which is kind of the opposite of what I am trying. Perhaps you could tell me how to get a type tag (or whatever will let me access the class symbol) for ``T`` in the macro above? (see update)

Comment: I think you're nearly there in your "update" section -- try using a "WeakTypeTag" instead of a ClassTag as the compiler suggests: "macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences"

Comment: @Rich tried (see update). I must be using the buggers wrong.? Also, wouldn't I end up getting a tag for ``Object``?

Comment: I'm convinced you're almost there. Do you have an example project I can clone and tweak?

Comment: Try "`c.WeakTypeTag`" instead of "`__root__.WeakTypeTag`"? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399998/is-it-possible-to-generate-apply-from-weaktypetag-inside-a-scala-macro

Answer (score 0):

> How do I actually get that "representation of T"?

You need to use `c.WeakTypeTag`, as hinted at by the compiler message you found in your "UPDATE" section.

This project has a working example that you can adapt: https://github.com/underscoreio/essential-macros/blob/master/printtype/lib/src/main/scala/PrintType.scala

```
object PrintTypeApp extends App {
  import PrintType._

  printSymbol[List[Int]]
}

import scala.language.experimental.macros

import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.util.{ Try => ScalaTry }

object PrintType {
  // Macro that generates a `println` statement to print
  // declaration information of type `A`.
  //
  // This only prints meaningful output if we can inspect
  // `A` to get at its definition:
  def printSymbol[A]: Unit =
    macro PrintTypeMacros.printTypeSymbolMacro[A]
}

class PrintTypeMacros(val c: Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def printTypeSymbolMacro[A: c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Tree =
    printSymbol(weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol, "")
}
```